# Returning a variable in btn.clicked.connect() method in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have called a function initUI in **init**() of a class through btn.clicked.connect(initUI). The function initUI() contains a fileName variable which I want to return to **init** function. How can I do this?

I have written a return statement in initUI() function to return variable fileName. I accepted the variable like this: btn.clicked.connect(a=initUI).

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,QWidget):

def __init__(self,parent=None):

     num=btn.clicked.connect(a=self.initUI)
def initUI(self):
    fn="The file Path"
    return fn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  # ,QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel()        
        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.initUI)        

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

    def initUI(self):
        fn = "The file Path"
        self.label.setText(fn)
#        return fn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: So it worked but I removed the grid layout part and used a textbox using QLineEdit instead of a label so that I can place it wherever I want on the screen. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As @S.Nick example shows you, you are going about it in the wrong way.  The function you redirect the button click to ought to handle setting whatever if is you need set and not pass it directly back.  Basically within the class you need a property to hold this value

```
@property
def classFilePath(self):
    return self.__FilePathName

@classFileName.setter
def classFilePath(self, value):
    self.__FilePathName = value

def __init__(self,parent=None):
     num=btn.clicked.connect(self.initUI)

def initUI(self):
    self.classFilePath ="The file Path"
```

This might seem like a little extra work but it makes for easier reading and for easier modifications later on.  Further the actual variable is not overtly made public (I say overtly because if you know how classes are handled in Python you know there are no true private variables just obfuscated ones).